"google-translate" is a tag, but it has 1 question only. Should we have a Wiktionary tag? Should we even have "google-translate"?
google-translate - One question tagged, but a search gets more than 350 questions.
https://chinese.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiktionary+is%3Aquestion - almost 150 questions.

You can see a bunch of single-use tags on the tags page.  They are automatically removed after six months.
My preference is to let them get auto-removed, since the users creating them are often either new (in which case editing them away may be confusing) or are passionate about a narrow topic (in which case editing them away may be irksome [or maybe it's a reasonable tag, but there's just not enough questions about it; maybe they'll ask some more]).  In the end, almost nobody is affected by single-use tags.  Besides, seldom-used tags are always a bit ratty, since the lack of questions means its unclear how to use them.
For this google-translate tag in particular, it seems translation is the appropriate tag (feel free to edit---everyone should be able to make or propose edits).  The question isn't really about Google Translate.
If we want a tag along these lines, it'd be better to create e.g. machine-translation, since there's also Baidu, Bing, Facebook, WeChat, and a bunch of other machine translation methods.  But a question with this hypothetical tag should be about machine translation, and not just be added because the OP is trying to understand a sentence by Google Translate (after all, we don't tag questions "website", "my-Chinese-friend", "street-sign").  But if the question is genuinely about machine translation, it might be better off on another Stack Exchange site.
Regarding a wiktionary tag, there's already a dictionary tag.
I remember years ago creating a cc-cedict tag for questions relating to editing the CC-CEDICT dictionary (such as this).  The tag eventually died out.  When it comes down to it, the reason we have tags is to index what the question is about (the meaning or etymology of words, how grammar patterns work, etc.), and questions are seldom about Wiktionary itself.
